# Get a list of asset files that are used in Community Builder?

Tags: community-builder, content-assets

Is there a quick way to get a list of Asset Files that are used in Community Builder for logo, background etc?

In Classic, I can go to Setup > Salesforce Files > Asset Files, open each file record and click Where is this Used, but this is pretty tedious.

I've tried the following but found nothing:

- Looked in Community Builder.  There's no indication of the actual asset files in use.
- Looked at the asset file detail page in Lightning.  There's no indication of usage.
- Downloaded the metadata (ExperienceBundle, ContentAsset, NetworkBranding, etc) and searched the xml files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is available in experience bundle.

Once you retrieve the experience bundle, look into

> `experiences > Community name > brandingSets > .json file.`

You should have something like this.

Note the name and then goto setup > Asset files to find the file.

---

[image]

Comment: That's it!  for some reason I had an old version of the ExperienceBundle metadata on my local drive.  Once I refreshed, my search found the items.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post while searching for a complete list of all Asset files used in the Community, *whether or not they are in the Template*. I needed this to identify the superset for initial deployment.

For the edification of those who may stumble across this using their Google Machine, this query worked for me:

```
select Id, ContentDocument.Title from Contentdocumentlink where Linkedentityid in (select ID from Network where Name = 'Support Community')
```

You will need to be a member of the Asset Library, or have Query All Files permission.